# Is it possible to have private elements of an array, but a public sum?

Tags: privacy

I will be performing a cost-benefit analysis soon and would like to determine the average salary of a small group of people, while maintaining the anonymity and even the distribution of the individual amounts, to the group and any third parties.  The group is small enough that guesses could be made based on seniority, etc. if the distribution would be known.

Are there any algorithms or systems by which the individual salaries could be trusted to remain private by all parties, but the overall sum would be public?

Comment: If ti is *not* a normal distribution (salaries rarely are).  Even giving the mean and the standard deviation will not give the distribution.

Comment: This is a pretty well known puzzle... https://www.google.com/search?q=salary+sum+puzzle finds the standard answer: first person adds his salary to a large random number, passes it to the next person who adds his salary (and maybe another large random number)... pass it on, second time around the circle everybody subtracts the random number they added the first time, end result is the sum. The major weakness is that any N-1 people can play the game again, revealing the excluded person's salary.

Comment: Do you also need to maintain the anonymity *to you*? If not, can they not just send you their salary, you calculate the average and only share that?